# Knit HTML - Recover from Error?

Tags: html, r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

I have a pretty long R code that takes approx 2-3 hours to run and Knit to HTML. However even with minor errors or warning.. the Knit aborts.. In the below example it has done so due to savehistory error.

```
processing file: model_v64.Rmd
  |......................                                           |  33%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...........................................                      |  67%
label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options) 
List of 1
 $ echo: logi TRUE


Quitting from lines 21-278 (model_v64.Rmd) 
**Error in .External2(C_savehistory, file) : no history available to save**
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> savehistory
Execution halted
```

Is there any way in which we can

1. Option 1 - Recover the partially created HTML from tmp directories or anywhere else
2. Option 2 - Get Knit HTML to continue on errors and not halt the code.
3. Option 3 - atleast save the already Knit HTML and then stop.

Thanks, Manish

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the chunk option `error = TRUE` to display the error instead of halting R:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(error = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks.. I used ```{r echo=TRUE, message=TRUE, error=TRUE}

Comment: Is there a way to resume after fixing the error instead of rerunning from the top?